# c# - UWP ListView displays incorrect items upon rapid scrolling when it has a DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp

I have a ListView that is intended to show every product within a database, and it works for the most part, but when I scroll down by dragging the scroll bar, the bottom items end up being incorrect.

XAML Definition:

```xml
<ListView x:Name="lst_Products" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="16,124,16,16" Width="300" ContainerContentChanging="lst_Products_ContainerContentChanging" Loaded="lst_Products_Loaded" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="16">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Value}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The data template is present so I can easily grab a product ID number with SelectedValue. According to some trusted community member (or whatever they call the prominent posters) on the MSDN forums said that's the only way to properly show a `ListView` when the `ItemsSource` is an `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int,RelativePanel>>` while having a selectable value member.

The relevant C# code:

```cs
private async void lst_Products_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var products = await ProductManager.GetProducts();
    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<int, RelativePanel>> productList = new(products);
    lst_Products.ItemsSource = productList;
    lst_Products.SelectedValuePath = "Key";
}
```

```cs
private void lst_Products_ContainerContentChanging(ListViewBase sender, ContainerContentChangingEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.ItemIndex % 2 == 1)
    {
        args.ItemContainer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 128, 128, 128));
    }
    else
    {
        args.ItemContainer.Background = UIManager.GetDefaultBackground();
    }
}
```

```cs
public static async Task<List<KeyValuePair<int, RelativePanel>>> GetProducts()
{
    var productPanels = new List<KeyValuePair<int, RelativePanel>>();
    var productIDs = await SqlHandler.ReturnListQuery<int>($"SELECT id FROM {productTable}");
    var productNames = await SqlHandler.ReturnListQuery<string>($"SELECT name FROM {productTable}");
    var panels = new List<RelativePanel>();
    foreach(var name in productNames)
    {
        RelativePanel panel = new();
        
        TextBlock productName = new()
        {
            Text = name
        };
        panel.Children.Add(productName);
        panels.Add(panel);
    }
        
    for(int i = 0; i < productIDs.Count; i++)
    {
        productPanels.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(productIDs[i], panels[i]));
    }
    return productPanels;
}
```

The call to SQL Handler just runs an SQL query and returns a list of the results. I can post the code if you need, but I can assure you there's no sorting going on.

[A screenshot of what the list looks like. The bottom item should be "Coffee" - Button Test Product 2 is the second item in the list.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neorl.png)

[A screenshot of the SQL datatable with the "Coffee" product at the bottom where it should be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAi71.png)

In this case it's just the bottom item that's incorrect, however other times it has jumbled 5 or 6 entries near the bottom. This only seems to occur with the DataTemplate/ContentPresenter, but without that, the RelativePanel does not display correctly in the list. Eventually the list will show more information about the product and as far as I can tell, there's no good way to do that without converting the SQL data into a RelativePanel on the c# side.

I'm open to suggestions on solving either the jumbling problem with the template, or adjusting the xaml so that I don't need the template to display bulk sql data without needing the template but I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

> c# - UWP ListView displays incorrect items upon rapid scrolling when it has a DataTemplate

The problem should be caused by listview [virtualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/listview-and-gridview-data-optimization), There are two ways to sloved this prolbem, one is disalbe listview virtualization by setting ItemsPanel as StackPanel like the following

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

And the other way is implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged?view=net-6.0) interface for your model class. for more please refer to [Data binding in depth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)

It's not good practice that use`RelativePanel` collection as datasoure,  the better way is make RelativePanel in your DataTemplate and bind with mode class property.

For example

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Index}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsItem}" />
            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```